# PHP preg match pattern [var1] var2

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get started with preg_match, but I could not get the right pattern.

The string looks like `[abc] def [ghi] jul [mno]` pqr.

I need something like `array(abc => def, ghi => jul, mno => pqr)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your effort. We are not here to do your homework!!!

Comment: I tried some examples but I couldnt find out how this really works.

Comment: @mrmow let see my answer and say what you want if my code will not working.

Comment: \[(.*)\] (.*) only works for one

Comment: `.*` is very veeery slow. Use for simple `[^\]]` but not `.*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex

```
/\[([a-z]+)\]( [a-z]+)?/
```

in `preg_match_all()`

After that try

```
$regex = '/\[([a-z]+)\][ ]?([a-z]+)?/';
$string = '[abc] def [ghi] jul [mno] pqr';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

$arr = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $index => $match){
    $arr[$match] = $matches[2][$index];
}

print_r($arr);
```

You can add `isset()` for `$matches[2][$index]` but I think my code is also works.

**@MateiMihai** suggestion `$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);`

Comment: What about `\[([a-z]+)\](\s[a-z]+)?` ? It is really a bad practice to use whitespace instead of `\s`

Comment: Surely you don't want to capture the spaces? `\[([a-z]+)\](?:[\s]?)([a-z]+)?`

Comment: @ling.s @Ankh but `\s` capture also new lines and others: https://regex101.com/r/pJ2xO7/1

Comment: I would use `$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);` instead of that foreach